# How to add and remove class?

Tags: jquery, class, addition

I know there are multiple similar questions, but I couldn't figure it out from them.

I have a list with three items and three correlating anchors at different parts of the page pointing to the items.

When an anchor is clicked I want the correlating list item's anchor to get a class of "cur" (for current) as illustrated below. And at the same time remove the class "cur" from either of the other two list items.

Here are the anchors:

```
<a href="#text-3" id="openSidebar"></a>
<a href="#text-5" id="about"></a>
<a href="#twitter-5" id="socialMedia"></a>
```

Here is the list:

```
<ul class="thumbNav">
<li class="first"><a href="#" class="panel1 cur">1</a></li>    
<li   class=""><a href="#" class="panel2">2</a></li>    
<li class="last"><a href="#" class="panel3">3</a></li></ul>
</ul>
```

So they all correlate respectively.

Comment: *""So they all correlate respectively.""* I've taken a look twice, now can you tell me again... what logic between then makes you say they are *Correlated* ? The only one I see is the `.index()` one.

Comment: When you click one of the said anchors it affects one of the lower list anchors, from top to bottom respectively.

Comment: Is any additional relationship between the anchors and the list?

Comment: Ok, but you've said: *""as illustrated below""* but below is illustrated just nothing. What's the parent of your `<a>` elements above? Does it has some ID... ? anything? Can you please explain where you see in the code you posted ANY logic to see they're Correlated? (Again... don't put in comments but rather edit your question! ) :)

Comment: I would first correct the fact that you are using class-names as though they were ids. Give the anchors the same class-name, this will help with the jQuery. You could give the li's the same class-name, although not essential (as the ul has a class-name).

Comment: "as illustrated below" was referring to the fact that the class "cur" was shown below and that's the format that it needs to appear.

Comment: You're right, but I cannot give them the same class name, the best I could do is give them those same class names as ID's as they must have separate names or the page is broken.

Comment: Also what have you tired with jQuery so far, or are you expecting us to to all your work for you?

Comment: It's not that I'm trying to do no work. It's that my attempts at trying are based off of something I don't fully understand from another question's answer that was similar to mine and I think would be of little to no use.

Comment: @user3727529 Again, I've asked you, what's the ID of the parent containing the *first three* `a` elements?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan There isn't one. They aren't grouped. They are scattered throughout the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a coresponding class to your list itmes

HTML

```
<div id="giveItAName">
<a href="#text-3" id="openSidebar"></a>
<a href="#text-5" id="about"></a>
<a href="#twitter-5" id="socialMedia"></a>
</div>

<ul class="thumbNav">
<li class="first openSidebar"><a href="#" class="panel1 cur">1</a></li>    
<li   class="about"><a href="#" class="panel2">2</a></li>    
<li class="last socialMedia"><a href="#" class="panel3">3</a></li></ul>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("#giveItAName a").click(function(){
      $("#thumNav a").removeClass("cur");

      var item = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#thumbNav ." + item + " a" ).addClass("cur");
})
```

**Update**

As the anchors are scattered about the page, gibe them a common class and use that as a selector:

```
<a href="#text-3" class="opener" id="openSidebar">Side Bar</a>
<a href="#text-5" class="opener" id="about">About</a>
<a href="#twitter-5" class="opener" id="socialMedia">Social</a>

<ul class="thumbNav">
    <li class="first openSidebar"><a href="#" class="panel1 cur">1</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="#" class="panel2">2</a></li>
    <li class="last socialMedia"><a href="#" class="panel3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.opener").click(function () {
    $(".thumbNav a").removeClass("cur");
    var item = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".thumbNav ." + item + " a").addClass("cur");
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q58fU/)

Comment: This is the issue I ran into with the question similar to mine. I can't put them in a div because they are anchored in different parts of the page.

Comment: YOu should mention that in your question

Comment: I will add it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: But what about the code, how does that change once I've given them all a common class?

Comment: It looks fine, but it isn't working. It succeeds in removing the class, but not in adding it.

Comment: Hacked it up a little bit and made it work. Thanks for you help.